# Configure date format used by FoxPro database

Tags: windows-server-2008, oledb, windows-server-2008-r2, foxpro, regional-settings

The problem in short: The same database returns dates in a different format on different servers and I'm having trouble to configure it to correct date format.

I have the following situation:
A PHP-based web application that gets it's data from Microsoft FoxPro 9 databases.
The database connection is made with OleDB. In PHP this utilises ADODB through COM objects:

```
$this->connection = new COM("ADODB.Connection");
$this->connection->Open($this->connectionString);
```

The connection string looks like this:

```
Provider=VFPOLEDB.1; Mode=Share Deny None; Window Handle=0; 
Locale Identifier=1033; Prompt=4; Extended Properties=0; 
User ID=; Password=; Mask Password=False; Cache Authentication=False; 
Encrypt Password=False; OLE DB Services=0; Collating Sequence=MACHINE; DSN=;
DELETED=True; ENGINEBEHAVIOR=80; TABLEVALIDATE=0; 
Data Source=\\path\to\file.DBC
```

The program is deployed on different servers throughout the world, running on different versions of Windows Server (2003-2008 R2). Query's are executed the following way:

```
$this->connection->Execute($query);
```

This returns a resultset with all values in plaintext. This is where the problem arises. The databases don't use the same formatting for dates, which makes it difficult to process the dates later on in PHP.
So far, the app can cope with the US format: mm/dd/yyyy and the dutch format: dd-mm-yyyy. The program just assumes that when the date contains slashes the US format is used and when there are hyphens the d-m-y format is used.
This has been going fine for a long time, but now we recently deployed the program to a server in Brazil, which returns dates in the Brazilian format dd/mm/yyyy. The program obviously now confuses this with the US format.

I've been trying to get the database to report in a different date format (US) to no avail.
On two different dev-environments, changing the Regional settings of windows to a different country immediately alters the date-format the database uses. These dev-environments are all Windows 7 systems.
However, this won't work on the servers with Windows Server. *I have changed around all of the Regional settings (Formats, Location and System locale) on multiple servers without any results.* Even after rebooting or reïnstalling FoxPro with the correct regional settings. The databases keep reporting in the date-format they seem stuck in.

**Does anybody know how I can change the date-format used by FoxPro on a Windows Server environment?**

Other options I have explored include putting regional information into the DSN, but couldn't I find any possible way. Also the FoxPro statement `SET DATE TO .....` is not accepted through OleDB.
Altering the application to understand the Brazilian format or to add a bunch of if-else statements doesn't seem like a feasible solution.

Answer (score 1):

The FoxPro date type is date-format-insensitive. That is, if you simply return the value as a date (datetime) rather than converting to character, you shouldn't have any problems.

Comment: That's true, but when the program receives the data it is in a ADO Recordset Object.
These are the functions I have to work with: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675841%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

I haven't found a way to get anything other then a string out of it.

Comment: The Field object has a Type property. I haven't worked with ADO enough to know how to specify it, but I'm sure you can.

Comment: Using the ADO API I'm not really finding a solution. Maybe I should switch to the ADO PHP Library: http://phplens.com/lens/adodb/docs-adodb.htm. Which has functions for date formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your FoxPro date field the [DTOC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h7dayzd0.aspx) function, with the second optional parameter.  This will return a standard YYYY-MM-DD style date, regardless of regional setting.

```
SELECT DTOC(dDate) as dDate FROM Alias
```

If that's not feasible, you'll need to investigate the functions to explicitly set a locale in FoxPro, such as the intuitively named [SYS(3005)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa978567.aspx).

And if even that's not feasible, you'll need to resort to requiring servers in foreign countries to have their regional settings standardized at the OS level.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe be explicit in your query and handle reconstructing the date within the web application. So if you have a date-type field in VFP called MyDate then do:

```
select x, y, z, day(MyDate) as daynum, month(MyDate) as monthnum, ;
year(MyDate) as yearnum from mytable
```

OK, so it's more work on the other reconstructing a date from that but at least it should be location-agnostic.

Comment: I agree that would be better, but I'm dealing with a lot of legacy code here. Unfortunately it's not perfect OOP, so changing all the queries and code that processes the data is not really feasible.